# MySQL, fetch, num_rows error

Tags: php

Okay so, hello!
I've recently had many errors so I actually don't know what causes this one to be an error, but here's the code:

```
// Outputs all the banned IP's if any
function  fetch_banned() {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECTT * FROM ip_ban ORDER BY datetime DESC");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {
        // if found ips
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<b>". $data['0'] ."</b> was banned on <b>". $data['1'] ."</b>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There are No IP's banned!";   
    }
} 

?>
```

The code error is from if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0) {

And here's the error:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a3047131/public_html/core/inc/ipban.inc.php on line 37
```

I'm very new to coding, so I'm pretty lost in these errors and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have typo in your query SELECTT should be SELECT.

change your :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECTT * FROM ip_ban ORDER BY datetime DESC");
```

to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_ban ORDER BY datetime DESC");
```

Comment: Wow such a retard, thanks so much! Didn't see that, error is solved thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECTT * FROM ip_ban ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM ip_ban ORDER BY datetime DESC
```